# How does avoiding anaemic domain models work with ORMs, Dependency Injection and a Solid approach

Tags: entity-framework, orm, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design

having looked at Domain Driven Design and read about Anaemic Domain Models being an antipattern, thinking ok perhaps should put more behaviour into our domain entities. The Behaviour will need handling for flexibility using SOLID approach, hence the need for a DI framework and container to allow injecting some behaviours into the entities.

However there appears a mismatch in wiring up the Entities, as our Entities would coming from an ORM framework such as Entity Framework or NHibernate, and Behaviours coming from a Dependency Injection container.

I guess you need a way for the ORM to also have a DI Container plugged into it.

Just wondering how others have approached this when wanting to get more rich models but also use ORMs and DI containers.

Comment: [DDD Usually does **not** inject sth to the entities](http://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/03/04/How-not-to-inject-services-in-entities).

Comment: In addition to not injecting anything into an entity I also do my utmost to avoid an ORM.  I still do my own persistence/mapping though but it leaves my domain totally persistence ignorant.  For ORMs you are probably going to need to have another DB-oriented layer or fiddle with your domain, even if it means just making methods virtual.

Comment: My ORM entities are separate from my domain entities.

Comment: Just check the DDD sample apps: http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Also what does DI have to do with Behaviour? The Behaviour has to be embedded in you Domain (Entities and Services) without injecting any third party Components.

Answer (score 4):

1- It is not a good idea to use ORM entities as your domain entities. Because your domain entities constitute the core of your DDD application and should have the minimum dependencies. What if you decide to change your ORM in the future? ORM can be used in your Repositories but remember that you need to map the ORM entities to your domain entities before your repository returns them.

2- Your domain entities should have behaviors but they are limited to that entity only. Any behaviors that involve other services or dependencies should go to a domain service. So your domain entities wouldn't have dependency on other services. They usually don't even need abstraction, so they won't need to be resolved using an IoC container.

Answer (score 0):

I came upon one potential answer after watching [this excellent video](http://vimeo.com/43598193) by Jimmy Bogard on Crafting Wicked Domain Models.

So your domain model contains the behaviour and rich methods, but you inject into the method of the domain model specific behaviours which implement some interface and are bits of functionality that you can get out of a DI container.

So by altering what you inject into the model, we can alter its behaviour using DI whilst still having a rich domain model and retrieving it from the database via an ORM.